# SQLite allows insert of string data into datetime column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE logaction
(
  actype varchar(8) not null,
  actime DATETIME not null,
  devid int not null
);
```

SQL:

```
insert into logaction values ('TEST', '2013-08-22', 1);
insert into logaction values ('TEST', '2013-08-22 09:45:30', 1);
insert into logaction values ('TEST', 'xyz', 2); // shouldn't this fail?
```

The last record does make it into the table regardless of the non-datetime value for the actime column.  Why and how can I enforce that only good data go in?

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b0c73/3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there's just no DATETIME type in Sqlite...

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> ```
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich 
> on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
> ```
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

see [doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

You could have created your table like that, it wouldn't have changed anything.

```
CREATE TABLE logaction
(
  actype varchar(8) not null,
  actime NonexistingType not null,
  devid int not null
);
```

Comment: do you know how many bits the `INTEGER` supports ?  e.g. can i just put miliseconds from 1/1/1970?  i need precise timestamps

Comment: i just tested putting 1377181566303 in and it worked so it is all good.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, not really in sqlite - it doesn't have a datetime type - see section 1.2 in [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple work around:

```
CREATE TABLE logaction
(
  actype varchar(8) not null,
  actime DATETIME not null check( DATETIME(actime) is not null ),
  devid int not null
);

sqlite> insert into logaction values ('TEST', '2013-08-22', 1);
sqlite> insert into logaction values ('TEST', '2013-08-22 09:45:30', 1);
sqlite> insert into logaction values ('TEST', 'xyz', 2);
Error: constraint failed
sqlite>
```

Comment: yes but will this enable me to query and compare the `actime` column as a time and not a string ?

Comment: @amphibient you'll have to use date and time functions (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for any date/time comparison

Comment: @amphibient This is just a constraint, it won't make it a true DATETIME type.